# React Conditional rendering doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

React app with **react-router-dom: 4.3.1**:

Main App.js render:

```
render() {
        let routes = (
            <Switch>
                <Route component={LogIn} path="/login" />
                <Redirect to="/login" />
            </Switch>
        );

        if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            routes = (
                <Switch>
                    <Route component={ParcelListView} path="/" exact />
                    <Route component={StatusTable} path="/status" />
                    <Redirect to="/" />
                </Switch>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div className="app">
                {routes}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I see white screen When use this code, but when I assign to **routes** first or second **Switch** without *if* it works perfectly in both cases.

I guess the problem comes from assignment in *if* block. Is this some kind of async thing?

Comment: It looks fine. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: (It would make more sense to use `if`/`else` rather than always creating the first set only to replace it with the second sometimes, but it should *work* as is...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I found out that after assignment react router doesn't recognize provided path in Route component and always redirects

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that, and whether it relates to my comments above or the question itself...?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to set routes inside of a `<Switch />` component whatever the scenario and have either *public* or *private* route components. Here is a common approach:

```
const PublicRoute = ({
 isAuthenticated,
 component: Component,
 ...rest
}) => (
<Route
  {...rest}
  component={props => (
    isAuthenticated ? (
      <Redirect to="/somewhere" />
    ) : (
    <Component {...props} />
  ))}
 />
);

const PrivateRoute = ({
  isAuthenticated,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => (
<Route
  {...rest}
  component={props => (
    isAuthenticated ? (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Component {...props} />
      </div>
    ) : (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  )
  )}
  />
);
```

Both components take `component` (function) and `isAuthenticated`(boolean) as props and we pass the rest of the props down (`{...rest}`) anyway (`path` etc.)

This way you're able to allow/deny routes based on the `props`passed down to your components:

```
...your code

render() {
 <Switch>
  <PublicRoute path="/" component={YourPublicComponent} />
  <PrivateRoute path="/" isAuthenticated component={ParcelListView} />
 </Switch>
}
```

More at Tyler McGinnis's website: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/
Another post on the subject: https://medium.com/@tomlarge/private-routes-with-react-router-dom-28e9f40c7146

You'll be able to find a lot of stuff on the subject on the web